# Looping over TWO variable sets

Tags: bash, loops, variables

I need to write some bash script which will loop over two sets of the input files provided in the 2 separate dirs and join it together within one loop step as the inputs for some programm.
Problem is that each of two folders consist of 10 different files: i) i1, i2 .. i10  and ii)  j1, j2 ... j10 in the second but on each loop step I should to provide i1, j1  ;  i2, j2 etc  pairs as the inputs. Assuming that both i and j have shared keyword within its filenames I would to write something like

```
input1=/data/input1
input2=/data/input2

for element_i, element_j in input1 and input 2  # actually I don't know how to define this step properly
# provide some condition if part of title of the element from i1 = i2
#e.g
title1=$(basename "element_i")
title2=$(basename "element_j")
if title1==title2
# run my program here using both inputs with same names
program -i1 element_i i2 element_j
break #? add something to stop loop for each pair only! and continue for the next elements!
```

So I'll be very thankful for any solutions!

Comment: Files are separated only by the last integer value ???

Comment: actually both files has the same tittle naming but differs in the extension. E.g in first folder: file1.md, file2.md, file3.md etc ; in the second folder: file1.xz, file2,xz, file3.xz etc

Answer (score 0):

This is more accurate example. Below are the inputs from two folders

```
gleb@gpu2:/data2/Gleb/TEST/claire+7d4+md/water_analysis/MD1> ls tr_all
7D4-androsta.mdcrd  7D4-androste.mdcrd  7D4-decenal.mdcrd
gleb@gpu2:/data2/Gleb/TEST/claire+7d4+md/water_analysis/MD1> ls top_all
7D4-androsta.top  7D4-androste.top  7D4-apo.top  7D4-decenal.top
gleb@gpu2:/data2/Gleb/TEST/claire+7d4+md/water_analysis/MD1> ls
script.sh  top_all  tr_all  water.in~
```

and my script

```
workdir=/data2/Gleb/TEST/claire+7d4+md/water_analysis/MD1
all_traj=${workdir}/tr
all_top=${workdir}/top


for top in all_top and for traj in all_traj; do # ????
 top_n=$(basename "$top")
 traj_n=$(basename "$traj")
 # add here some condition to make below step only if top==traj
 # make input for my program including imputs from both dirs
 printf "parm ${top_n}\ntrajin ${traj_n}\nwatershell ${Area} watershell_${top_n}_${Area}.dat :WAT@O* lower $low upper $up" > ./water_${top_n}.in
```

what I'm looking for how to loop over two dirs correctly, 2) how to select only name from each file without its extension 3) and how to add some condition to make input only in both files has same name

James